# mkmapview in landscape mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Is it possble to show a map in landscape mode?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

The easiest way to accomplish it is to put your map view in a view controller that you then present in some way. Whatever orientations the view controller then supports will cause the hosted map view to rotate to automatically.

In your view controller you'd implement this method:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

That example handles both lanscape orientations. As long as your map view is set to autoresize correctly in your NIB file it should all just work.